# dynamically created delete button is not working in jquery and stopping immediate propagation

Tags: html, jquery

I have developed an inquiry form as per the need. The data to be entered may be of multiples for which I designed the dynamic form so that the rows may be increased or decreased. They are in tabular form, and the add button in the form is working fine but the delete button is not working and while debugging showing it stopped immediate propagation.

```js
var maxcounter = 10;
var passengercounter = 0;
$('#addpassenger').on('click', function(e) {
  if ($("#pname_").val() != "" && 
      $("#pemail_").val() != "" && 
      $("#pnumber_").val() != "") {
  if (passengercounter < maxcounter) {
    passengercounter++;
    var tableinnerhtml = $("#passenger_detail_table").html();
    var name = $("#pname_").val();
    var email = $("#pemail_").val();
    var number = $("#pnumber_").val();

    var newrowhtml = '<tr id="row_' + passengercounter + '">' +
      '<td><input id="pname_' + passengercounter + '"></td>' +
      '<td><input id="pemail_' + passengercounter + '"></td>' +
      '<td><input id="pnumber_' + passengercounter + '"></td>' +
      '<td> <button type="button" id="removepassengerid" class="removepassenger" data-id="'+passengercounter+'" style="background-color:red; color: white;" name="passenger_remove">Remove</button></td>'+
    '</tr>';

    $("#passenger_detail_table").append(newrowhtml);

    $("#pname_" + passengercounter).val(name);
    $("#pemail_" + passengercounter).val(email);
    $("#pnumber_" + passengercounter).val(number);
    $("#pname_" + passengercounter).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#pemail_" + passengercounter).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#pnumber_" + passengercounter).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#pname_").val("");
    $("#pemail_").val("");
    $("#pnumber_").val("");
  } else {
    alert("no more data to be placed")
  }
} else {
  alert("please enter the values...");
}
});

$("document").on('click', '#removepassenger', function() {
  alert("delete button clicked");
  var id = $('#removepassengerid').data('id');
  $("#row_" + id).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="passenger_detail_table" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr valign="top">
      <td>
        <label for="pname_" id="small-label">Name</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="pemail_" id="small-label">E-mail</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="pnumber_" id="small-label">Phone-Number</label>
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="pname_" type="text" name="passenger_name[]" value="" placeholder="Enter Name" required>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="pemail_" type="email" name="passenger_email[]" value="" placeholder="Enter E-mail" required>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="pnumber_" type="number" name="passenger_phone_number[]" value="" placeholder="Enter Phone-No" required>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" id="addpassenger" name="passenger_add" style="background-color:green;color:white;">Add</button>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. You had a trailing parenteses in the if and some issue with a long HTML string

Comment: $("document").on('click','#removepassenger',function(){
   alert("delete button clicked");
      var id = $('#removepassengerid').data('id');
   $("#row_"+id).remove();
   
  }); remove function is not working everytime I am clicking its doing nothing

Comment: See my answer. I use a class instead and closest to find the row

Comment: while debugging it showing it stopped bubbling or immediate propogation

Comment: There is no need for bubbling or propagation here. I am not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs MUST be unique and you keep adding the same ID to the button.

No need for all that saving of ID, just use a class and closest("tr")

```
$("#passenger_detail_table").on('click', '.passenger_remove', function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

using

```
<button type="button" class="passenger_remove">Remove</button>
```

```js
var maxcounter = 10;
var passengercounter = 0;
$('#addpassenger').on('click', function(e) {
  if ($("#pname_").val() != "" && 
      $("#pemail_").val() != "" && 
      $("#pnumber_").val() != "") {
  if (passengercounter < maxcounter) {
    passengercounter++;
    var tableinnerhtml = $("#passenger_detail_table").html();
    var name = $("#pname_").val();
    var email = $("#pemail_").val();
    var number = $("#pnumber_").val();

    var newrowhtml = '<tr id="row_' + passengercounter + '">' +
      '<td><input id="pname_' + passengercounter + '"></td>' +
      '<td><input id="pemail_' + passengercounter + '"></td>' +
      '<td><input id="pnumber_' + passengercounter + '"></td>' +
      '<td> <button type="button" style="background-color:red; color:white;" class="passenger_remove">Remove</button></td>'+
    '</tr>';

    $("#passenger_detail_table").append(newrowhtml);

    $("#pname_" + passengercounter).val(name);
    $("#pemail_" + passengercounter).val(email);
    $("#pnumber_" + passengercounter).val(number);
    $("#pname_" + passengercounter).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#pemail_" + passengercounter).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#pnumber_" + passengercounter).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#pname_").val("");
    $("#pemail_").val("");
    $("#pnumber_").val("");
  } else {
    alert("no more data to be placed")
  }
} else {
  alert("please enter the values...");
}
});

$("#passenger_detail_table").on('click', '.passenger_remove', function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="passenger_detail_table" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr valign="top">
      <td>
        <label for="pname_" id="small-label">Name</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="pemail_" id="small-label">E-mail</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="pnumber_" id="small-label">Phone-Number</label>
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="pname_" type="text" name="passenger_name[]" value="" placeholder="Enter Name" required>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="pemail_" type="email" name="passenger_email[]" value="" placeholder="Enter E-mail" required>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="pnumber_" type="number" name="passenger_phone_number[]" value="" placeholder="Enter Phone-No" required>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" id="addpassenger" name="passenger_add" style="background-color:green;color:white;">Add</button>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Why not clone?

```js
const maxCounter = 10;
const $tb = $("#passenger_detail_table tbody ");
let passengerCounter;
$('#addpassenger').on('click', function(e) {
  const pname   = $.trim($("#pname_").val())
  const pemail  = $.trim($("#pemail_").val())
  const pnumber = $.trim($("#pnumber_").val())
  if (pname === "" || pemail === "" || pnumber  === "") { 
    alert("Please enter  values...");   
    return;
  }
  passengerCounter = $tb.find("tr").length
  if (passengerCounter >= maxCounter) {
    alert("No more data to be placed")
    return;
  }

  const $firstRow = $tb.find(">:first-child");
  let $newrowhtml = $firstRow.clone(true);
  $firstRow.find(":input").val("");
  
  $newrowhtml.find(":input")
    .removeAttr("id","")
    .attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    
  $newrowhtml.find("[name*=_name]").val(pname);   
  $newrowhtml.find("[name*=_email]").val(pemail);   
  $newrowhtml.find("[name*=_number]").val(pnumber);   
  $newrowhtml.find("[name=passenger_add]").replaceWith($('<button type="button" style="background-color:red; color:white;" class="passenger_remove">Remove</button>'));

  $("#passenger_detail_table").append($newrowhtml);

});

$("#passenger_detail_table").on('click', '.passenger_remove', function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="passenger_detail_table" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr valign="top">
      <td>
        <label for="pname_" id="small-label">Name</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="pemail_" id="small-label">E-mail</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="pnumber_" id="small-label">Phone-Number</label>
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="pname_" type="text" name="passenger_name[]" value="" placeholder="Enter Name" required>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="pemail_" type="email" name="passenger_email[]" value="" placeholder="Enter E-mail" required>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="pnumber_" type="number" name="passenger_phone_number[]" value="" placeholder="Enter Phone-No" required>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" id="addpassenger" name="passenger_add" style="background-color:green;color:white;">Add</button>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @jyotsnashekhar Please accept this answer (checkmark to the left of the question) if it suits you so we can see you found your solution.

Comment: @jyotsnashekhar I updated my second example to copy the values and clear the inputs correctly

Comment: this is really helpful i will surely update my code thanks